# css3 pure: how to hover an element outside?

Tags: css

```
div.test:hover #sendBtn{
    color:red;
}
```

This works fine is sendBtn is INSIDE the div.test element

But how to achieve this (pure CSS) when it is outside ?
ex:

```
<button id="sendBtn">hello</button>
<div class='test'>div here</div>
```

Comment: Can the `div` be before the `button` element?

Comment: Can you change the order of the elements? CSS can only traverse down and not up. So if `#sendBtn` is after `.test` you can do `div.test:hover + #sendBtn{...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no selector for previous element in css but you can change the order of the elements and use [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

**html**

```
<div class='test'>div here</div>
<button id="sendBtn">hello</button>
```

**css**

```
div.test:hover + #sendBtn {
    color:red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joa5heLr/1/)